# Ocamlyacc seemingly not returning a full record

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I have the following parser which should return a record with `globalVars` and `globalFns`, but it doesn't appear to.

```
%start program
%type <Ast.program> program

%%

program:
    decls EOF { $1 }

decls:
      /* nothing */             { { globalVars = []; globalFns = []; } }
    | decls varDecl             { { $1 with globalVars  = $1::$2.globalVars  } }
    | decls fnDecl              { { $1 with globalFns   = $1::$2.globalFns  } }
```

where `ast.ml` defines a program as:

```
type program = {
    globalVars  : bind list;
    globalFns   : func_decl list;
}
```

The error I'm receiving is: `Error: Unbound record field globalVars` when I try to do something like:

```
let translate program =
    let global_vars =
        let global_var m (t, n) =
            let init = L.const_int (ltype_of_typ t) 0
            in StringMap.add n (L.define_global n init the_module) m in
            List.fold_left global_var StringMap.empty program.globalVars in
```

I simply cannot figure out why `program.globalVars` is unbound here. If someone could point me in the proper direction, that'd be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the record field `globalVars` that is unbound in the current scope not really `program.globalVars` itself: field labels lives in the module that defines them. In order to access a record field for a type defined outside of the current module; one needs to either use a fully qualified field paths, `program.Ast.globalVars` where `Ast.globalVars` is the path to the field `globalVars` defined in the module `Ast` or bring the field in scope, by opening the module for instance or annotating the type of program: `let translate (program:Ast.program)= …`.

Comment: Omg, I love you @octachron